Integrable function which is discontinuous on Cantor Set.
We know by Riemann Lebesgue theorem that any bounded function $f:[a,b]$ $\to R$ is Riemann Integrable if the set of discontinuity of $f$ is a measure zero set.
Now my question is : Is there any function $f$ which is discontinuous on Cantor Set?  (Since Cantor Set has measure zero but it's uncountable)
Also I may slightly generalized this as follows:
Is there any (class of) function(s) which is(are) Riemann Integrable but has discontinuities on an uncountable set(ofc Measure zero)?

How about the function that is $1$ on the Cantor set and $0$ elsewhere?

(A slight generalization of the example by MartianInvader)
The complement of the Cantor set in $[0,1]$ is a disjoint union of open intervals. Any function that is constant on each of those intervals is clearly countinuous on the complement of the Cantor set. If you choose different constants on different intervals, you can obtain plenty of examples.
For instance, if the Cantor set you consider is the classical one with Hausdorff dimension $\ln 2/\ln 3$, you can choose $f$ to be zero on the Cantor set and equal to $c_n$ on all $2^{n-1}$ intervals of length $3^{-n}$ as long as $(c_n)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers with
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} |c_n|>0. $$
It is less evident, but still true, that it is enough to assume
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} |c_n|>0, $$
i.e., there is no subsequence of $(c_n)$ converging to zero as $n\to\infty$.
These examples are all different one from the other, even when considering two functions equivalent when they are equal almost everywhere.
Another interesting property. As long as $\limsup c_n>\liminf c_n$, then even after modifying the function on a set of measure zero, it will still be discontinuous on all points of the Cantor set. In particular, the function is not even equivalent (equal a.e.) to a continuous function, or to a function with countably many discontinuities.

